# Reference static final variables in eclipse plugin.xml

Tags: xml, eclipse, variables, plugins

Is there an easy way (or any way) to reference static variables in the plugin.xml file for a plugin project?

For example, if I have a class like this in package pkg:

```
public class ClassWithVariable {
    public static final String VAR = "abc";
}
```

and I want to have say a menu item with this string as the label...

```
<menu
    label = pkg.ClassWithVariable.VAR
>
```

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys.  I ended up resolving my particular issue by using dynamic menu contributions.  Since this allows you to define menu items via code, it was no problem to access other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read a [tutorial on Eclipse plugin localization](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseInternationalization/article.html). Your problem is solved by moving the String into a properties file, which is then accessible from the Java code as well as from the plugin.xml.

The way you envisioned is not possible.

Comment: Okay, I had heard of properties files, but I wanted to know if this was possible at all.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. You have to use plugin properties localization declared by Bundle-Localization in your MANIFEST.MF.